# Using the Scan function to continue with code in R

Tags: r

I want to use the scan function in R in the way that I Want the letter "n" to be pressed to continue the code. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think `scan` is the best choice for this. Would you be okay with `readline` instead?

Comment: Also, what do you want to happen if the user enters something other than "n"?